# Excel Pivot Table find sum of value divided by number of days

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I want to find the total sum of sales divided by the number of days of the week in that month. So for a specific month the total sales averaged for a specific day during different parts of the day.

The Weekday field was created using the Weekday function (=WEEKDAY(B2,1)). The Interval field was created using the Floor function (=FLOOR([@[Created Time]], "1:00")) from the column with the order creation date.

The Weekday and Months are just slicers I added where month was one of the groupings added on the pivot table. I thought that adding a calculated field would be my best best, but I'm not sure if I just couldn't figure out the right way to do it or if it was the wrong method to try.

[image: Pivot Table]

Comment: To make your data useful **edit your question** to post it as **text**, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)